# How Do I stop VSCode from auto-filling unnecessary words on save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running this code and every time I save, it adds 3 other words that I didn't want to be added.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fuse = new Fuse(slideRows, { keys: ['data.description', 'data.title', 'data.genre'] });
    const results = fuse.search(searchTerm).map(({ item }) => item);
    
    if (slideRows.length > 0 && searchTerm.length > 3 && results.length > 0) {
        setSlideRows(results);
    } else {
        setSlideRows(slides[category]);
    }
  }, [category, searchTerm, slideRows, slides])
```

The last line of code I only one one word `searchTerm` but vs code keeps auto filling the array with the other 3 words.

Is there a setting to prevent this or how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it’s vscode and not an extension?

Answer (score 0):

because of this it will create infinite loop.you can disable eslint plugging and try if you are using that.because this will do auto filling.